# Do not insert data if Email already exist PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a web application for user to use their email and search for the table number and insert the Email in mysql table. If the email already in the table, I dont want it to be insert one more time. Below is the code I added in my php file.

```
INSERT INTO employee (phone_number)
     VALUES ('$search')
```

I have tried the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as well and it is not working. Below is the code I used in my php file.

```
INSERT INTO employee (phone_number)
     VALUES ('$search') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE phone_number = '$search'
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: You mention `email`, but you're only looking up `phone_number`.

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Have you set your `email` column to be unique?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY` requires a KEY !! If you show us your schema .... Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` in phpMyAdmin or similiar or the mysql command line and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: The answer is very simple -> add validation to form -> `function find_email($email) {...}`

Comment: do you know what it is `SQL Injection`?

Comment: @aynber actually the phone_number is my email.

Comment: @Mantykora7 I am not sure, I am new to PHP

Comment: @brombeer I dont want my email column to be unique cause I want the user to be able to search for their table number again incase they forget.

Comment: @Khai ok my advice is: before you start doing anything in php you need to take some course, linkedin or udemy

Comment: @RiggsFolly, my table structure is only ID and phonenumber (which is the email).

Comment: Yes, I am learning a course on Udemy, wanted to try and learn, but stuck in this project.

Comment: You cannot use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` unless 1) you have a key and 2) it is set as unique

Comment: First, I'd recommend using properly descriptive names for your columns. Putting email addresses in a field named phone_number will confuse you and anyone else who works on the code later. You'll need to add a `unique` constraint to that field in order to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. You can still search for the value, but it makes it so that you can't have the same value in multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the people that help me in the comment area. I manage to figure it out with the help. You will need to set the email to unique in the database to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY.

Also got found some articles on the internet talking about SQL Injection and knowing that using proper name for columns is very important. Thanks for the help from everyone in the comment area again.